# how to write qunit for javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I'm not really into qunit but would like to get into.
Can someone guide me to write qunit test for simple js script I just wrote? Script works just fine.

Here is full script.

```
(function ($) {

    My.UserCenter = My.View.extend({
        cookie_name: 'my_norefresh',
        events: {
            'click input.options': 'togglePortalRefresh'
        },
        initialize: function (options) {
            My.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            this.$el.find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger: 'hover focus'});
            if (this.getCookie() === '1') {
                $('#optionOn').parent().addClass('buttongray');
                $('#optionOff').parent().addClass('buttonblue');
            }
            else {
                $('#optionOn').parent().addClass('buttonblue');
                $('#optionOff').parent().addClass('buttongray');
            }
        },
        togglePortalRefresh: function() {
            var cookie_exist = this.getCookie();
            if (typeof cookie_exist === 'undefined' || cookie_exist === null) {
              this.setCookie();
            }
            else {
                this.deleteCookie();
            }
            $('#optionOn').parent().toggleClass('buttongray buttonblue');
            $('#optionOff').parent().toggleClass('buttongray buttonblue');
        },
        getCookie: function() {
            return $.cookie(this.cookie_name);
        },
        setCookie: function() {
            $.cookie(this.cookie_name, '1', {
                expires: 9999,
                path: '/'
            });
        },
        deleteCookie: function() {
            $.cookie(this.cookie_name, null, {
                expires: -1,
                path: '/'
            });
        }
    });
} (My.$));
```

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I think this is an overly broad topic spanning several questions, including first determining _what_ to test, then working out _how_ to do that test. I would recommend starting with [Introduction to Unit Testing](http://qunitjs.com/intro/), it covers many scenarios.

Comment: Agreed, SO is not the place for guides or tutorials. Try the [QUnit site](https://qunitjs.com/cookbook/)!